# Getting "Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch" on python

Tags: python, heroku, server, webhooks

I'm developing an app on Python using flask and I'm getting this error while trying to deploy it to Heroku:

> Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

On the Heroku logs, I can see this line 
[image]

Few possibilities that I have tried

1. In my Procfile I have written this `web: python hello-mysql.py`
2. I have also tried `web: python hello-mysql.py runserver 0.0.0.0=$PORT`
3. Replace "web" with "worker" in your Procfile.

Comment: If you look at your log lines, your app is starting on port 5000. It needs to start on the port set at $PORT

Comment: @DamienMATHIEU I have tried $PORT...but from your point of view can you tell me how it will work?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using any of the Python standard servers such as gunicorn. So you need to handle the port yourself when booting the server, with `os.environ['PORT']` instead of 5000.

Answer (score 1):

To @damien's point, it looks like you're not binding to the `$PORT` env var. Here's some documentation that may help: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#define-a-procfile and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#web-dynos

Also, do not rename your process to "worker" since only processes named `web` will be accessible via http/https.

Comment: How do you bind to the `$PORT` env var?  In my case I am using selenium to automate some tasks in Chrome and getting the same error.

Comment: @JacekTrociński Same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, use `gunicorn` to easen the burden.

- Within the project directory, with the virtual environment activated, install `gunicorn` as follows:

```
pip install gunicorn
```

- If you're using `pipenv` you can try:
  `pipenv install gunicorn`
- Update the `requirements.txt` file to include the new installed `gunicorn` module by running:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

- Update the `Procfile` as follows:

```
web: gunicorn your_django_project_name.wsgi --log-file -
```

N.B:
There should be space between the `web:` and `gunicorn` as well as between `--log-file` and the `-` next to it.

Lastly, add, commit and push the changes